# GROUP BY CSV columns in bash

Tags: bash, csv, sum, aggregate

I am working with a .csv file in bash and I need to SUM the last value of each row depending on the previous fields. That is, I need to group in Bash by the first three columns.

Example of input file:

```
Barcelona, Female, suspect, 2
Barcelona, Female, positive, 3
Barcelona, Female, positive, 2
Barcelona, Male, positive, 1
Barcelona, Female, suspect, 5
Madrid, Male, positive, 3
Madrid, Male, positive, 1
Barcelona, Male, positive, 4
Madrid, Female, suspect, 2
```

Example of output file:

```
Barcelona, Female, suspect, 7
Barcelona, Female, positive, 5
Barcelona, Male, positive, 5
Barcelona, Female, suspect, 5
Madrid, Male, positive, 4
Madrid, Female, suspect, 2
```

Comment: `Barcelona, Female, suspect, 7` `Barcelona, Female, suspect, 5` in the output file are repeated - the line with `5` I guess shouldn't be there. So what have you tried?

Comment: have you tried any of the solutions? how did it go? Here in stack exchange, after you ask a question and have answers, you should always to return a feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Barcelona, Female, Suspect
bfs() {
        BFS_FILTER=$(egrep -i "[Bb]arcelona, [Ff]emale, [Ss]uspect" data.csv | awk '{ print $4 }')
        BFS_CASES=$(for ITEM in ${BFS_FILTER}; do echo $ITEM; done |tr \\n " " |sed "s| | + |g" |sed "s/\+ $//g")
        BFS_SUM=$(if [ $(echo $BFS_CASES |egrep -v ^$ |wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then echo 0; else if [ $(echo $BFS_CASES |wc -w) -eq 2 ]; then echo $BFS_CASES |awk '{ print $1 }'; else expr ${BFS_CASES}; fi; fi )

        echo "Barcelona, Female, suspect, $BFS_SUM"
}

# Barcelona, Male, Suspect
bms() {
        BMS_FILTER=$(egrep -i "[Bb]arcelona, [Mm]ale, [Ss]uspect" data.csv | awk '{ print $4 }')
        BMS_CASES=$(for ITEM in ${BMS_FILTER}; do echo $ITEM; done |tr \\n " " |sed "s| | + |g" |sed "s/\+ $//g")
        BMS_SUM=$(if [ $(echo $BMS_CASES |egrep -v ^$ |wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then echo 0; else if [ $(echo $BMS_CASES |wc -w) -eq 2 ]; then echo $BMS_CASES |awk '{ print $1 }'; else expr ${BMS_CASES}; fi; fi )

        echo "Barcelona, Male, suspect, $BMS_SUM"
}

# Barcelona, Female, Positive
bfp() {
        BFP_FILTER=$(egrep -i "[Bb]arcelona, [Ff]emale, [Pp]ositive" data.csv | awk '{ print $4 }')
        BFP_CASES=$(for ITEM in ${BFP_FILTER}; do echo $ITEM; done |tr \\n " " |sed "s| | + |g" |sed "s/\+ $//g")
        BFP_SUM=$(if [ $(echo $BFP_CASES |egrep -v ^$ |wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then echo 0; else if [ $(echo $BFP_CASES |wc -w) -eq 2 ]; then echo $BFP_CASES |awk '{ print $1 }'; else expr ${BFP_CASES}; fi; fi )

        echo "Barcelona, Female, positive, $BFP_SUM"
}

# Barcelona, Male, Positive
bmp() {
        BMP_FILTER=$(grep -i "[Bb]arcelona, [Mm]ale, [Pp]ositive" data.csv | awk '{ print $4 }')
        BMP_CASES=$(for ITEM in ${BMP_FILTER}; do echo $ITEM; done |tr \\n " " |sed "s| | + |g" |sed "s/\+ $//g")
        BMP_SUM=$(if [ $(echo $BMP_CASES |egrep -v ^$ |wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then echo 0; else if [ $(echo $BMP_CASES |wc -w) -eq 2 ]; then echo $BMP_CASES |awk '{ print $1 }'; else expr ${BMP_CASES}; fi; fi )

        echo "Barcelona, Male, positive, $BMP_SUM"
}

# Madrid, Female, Suspect
mfs() {
        MFS_FILTER=$(egrep -i "[Mm]adrid, [Ff]emale, [Ss]uspect" data.csv | awk '{ print $4 }')
        MFS_CASES=$(for ITEM in ${MFS_FILTER}; do echo $ITEM; done |tr \\n " " |sed "s| | + |g" |sed "s/\+ $//g")
        MFS_SUM=$(if [ $(echo $MFS_CASES |egrep -v ^$ |wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then echo 0; else if [ $(echo $MFS_CASES |wc -w) -eq 2 ]; then echo $MFS_CASES |awk '{ print $1 }'; else expr ${MFS_CASES}; fi; fi )

        echo "Madrid, Female, suspect, $MFS_SUM"
}

# Madrid, Male, Suspect
mms() {
        MMS_FILTER=$(egrep -i "[Mm]adrid, [Mm]ale, [Ss]uspect" data.csv | awk '{ print $4 }')
        MMS_CASES=$(for ITEM in ${MMS_FILTER}; do echo $ITEM; done |tr \\n " " |sed "s| | + |g" |sed "s/\+ $//g")
        MMS_SUM=$(if [ $(echo $MMS_CASES |egrep -v ^$ |wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then echo 0; else if [ $(echo $MMS_CASES |wc -w) -eq 2 ]; then echo $MMS_CASES |awk '{ print $1 }'; else expr ${MMS_CASES}; fi; fi )

        echo "Madrid, Male, suspect, $MMS_SUM"
}

# Madrid, Female, Positive
mfp() {
        MFP_FILTER=$(egrep -i "[Mm]adrid, [Ff]emale, [Pp]ositive" data.csv | awk '{ print $4 }')
        MFP_CASES=$(for ITEM in ${MFP_FILTER}; do echo $ITEM; done |tr \\n " " |sed "s| | + |g" |sed "s/\+ $//g")
        MFP_SUM=$(if [ $(echo $MFP_CASES |egrep -v ^$ |wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then echo 0; else if [ $(echo $MFP_CASES |wc -w) -eq 2 ]; then echo $MFP_CASES |awk '{ print $1 }'; else expr ${MFP_CASES}; fi; fi )

        echo "Madrid, Female, positive, $MFP_SUM"
}

# Madrid, Male, Positive
mmp() {
        MMP_FILTER=$(grep -i "[Mm]adrid, [Mm]ale, [Pp]ositive" data.csv | awk '{ print $4 }')
        MMP_CASES=$(for ITEM in ${MMP_FILTER}; do echo $ITEM; done |tr \\n " " |sed "s| | + |g" |sed "s/\+ $//g")
        MMP_SUM=$(if [ $(echo $MMP_CASES |egrep -v ^$ |wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then echo 0; else if [ $(echo $MMP_CASES |wc -w) -eq 2 ]; then echo $MMP_CASES |awk '{ print $1 }'; else expr ${MMP_CASES}; fi; fi )

        echo "Madrid, Male, positive, $MMP_SUM"
}

bfs
bms
bfp
bmp
mfs
mms
mfp
mmp
```

It is based on data extracted from a file I called `data.csv`, so you will have to replace every `data.csv` coincidence on it with your file's name **before** running it to make it work. For example, if you save it as `script.sh` and your input file is called `yourfile.csv`, you could try:

```
sed -i "s|data.csv|yourfile.csv|g" script.sh
```

The reason to separate every output into different functions is that if you want to filter out some of them at any time you could do this with no extra effort, just comment the function's name and you are done. Also, you could add extra cases by simply copy-pasting the schema and replacing the new variable names properly.

Now the explanation:

The row of number cases filter is made via:

`egrep -i "$CITY, $GENRE, $STATUS" data.csv | awk '{ print $4 }'`

Then, the sum of every row found works like this:

`for ITEM in ${SOME_FILTER}; do echo $ITEM; done |tr \\n " " |sed "s| | + |" |sed "s/\+ $//g"`

Where it outputs `expr $NUM + $NUM ...` in case there are more than 2 rows. But if there are not (which I detected there are cases that only shows positive number cases in only one row), I filter them with this method:

- If there is only one row with more than one case, just print it
- If there are multiple rows, sum each of them
- If there are no cases but the function is called and the rows exist, print 0

Lastly, it also prints a line when there are no detected cases, just via `echo 0`. An example output:

```
Barcelona, Female, suspect, 7
Barcelona, Male, suspect, 0
Barcelona, Female, positive, 5
Barcelona, Male, positive, 5
Madrid, Female, suspect, 2
Madrid, Male, suspect, 0
Madrid, Female, positive, 0
Madrid, Male, positive, 4
```

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 4):

[GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) is designed just for this sort of task:

```
datamash -t, -sg1,2,3 sum 4 < input.csv
```

Or with `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{ groups[$1 "," $2 "," $3] += $4}
         END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" # Sort output in GNU awk
               for (g in groups) print g "," groups[g] }' input.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```sh
mlr --csv -N stats1 -a sum -f 4 -g 1,2,3 input.csv
```

you have

```
Barcelona, Female, suspect,7
Barcelona, Female, positive,5
Barcelona, Male, positive,5
Madrid, Male, positive,4
Madrid, Female, suspect,2
```